# OpenCV reading MP4 gives all zero frames

Tags: python, opencv, mp4

I have been trying to read this mp4 file frame by frame using python-opencv. The following is my code.

```
import cv2
filename = '<absolute path>/HandWash_014_A_11_G_03.mp4'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame, ret)
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I print the frame immediately after reading, I get all zero arrays as follows. Then I tried reading a different mp4 file in the same folder but that returns non-zero values successfully. Also, please note that this problematic file can be successfully played using a media player (I tried Quicktime player).

```
    [[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

I am actually trying to read files from this Kaggle dataset each frame by frame
https://www.kaggle.com/realtimear/hand-wash-dataset

Please help me understand the issue here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the video file is corrupt or is incompatible with opencv. a video player can read it because its designed to try compensate for those problem files. the best shot is to reencode the video using handbrake or similar. ususally that fixes the problem for me

Comment: Thanks, that sounds to be the solution.